# Launching remote kernel--increase timeout time

Tags: kernel, remote-access, kernel-startup

When launching several remote kernels manually on a cluster (as described in [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ParallelTools/tutorial/ConnectionMethods.html) under `Remote Kernels/Manual Launching') I see quite frequently the following error:

```
General::time: Operation LaunchKernels timed out after 10. seconds.
```

(and of course, these kernels do not start). My guess: if the remote kernel does not launch in a given time (10 seconds) then the controlling kernel interrupts and continues with the next kernel (if requested). Thus my question: is it possible to modify (in particular to increase) the timeout time? Given limited documentation (both `LaunchRemote` and `LinkCreate` do not give much information) I could not find any solution to this issue.

To be more specific here is the code I use to launch 8 remote kernels on a particular host "node642" (all machines are running Linux, with same version of Mathematica installed on each machine) using ssh connection:

```
Needs["SubKernels`RemoteKernels`"];
LaunchKernels[RemoteMachine["node642", "ssh -x -f -l `3` `1` /wolfram/mathematica/11.2.0/bin/math -mathlink -linkmode Connect `4` -linkname '`2`' -subkernel -noinit -nopaclet >& /dev/null &", 8]]
```

For obvious reasons, I am interested in a solution which does not requre using GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [SetSystemOptions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetSystemOptions.html) to increase the timeout used upon launching remote kernels:

```
SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "MathLinkTimeout" -> 20.]
```

Comment: This worked for me. Many thanks!